# JQueryUI changing order of LIs not reflected in DOM on JQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui, dom

I have a page with two `asp:BulletedLists`, an available items list and a selected items list, one is populated the other is not, and I can drag and drop LIs between them no problem. I am using two hidden fields to persist the contents of each list, when I do a postback, what is in each list (reading from the persisting hidden fields) is correct, however not in the order that is selected by the user, items are moved between each list and in the UI they do appear to be in the order that the user defines on the page, however this change of ordering is not reflected in the `DOM` when I am looping through the `.each()` method.

My code...

```
    $(function () {
        $("#<%= blAvailableDocuments.ClientID %>").sortable();
        $("#<%= blAvailableDocuments.ClientID %>").disableSelection();

        $("#<%= blSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").sortable();
        $("#<%= blSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").disableSelection();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#<%= blAvailableDocuments.ClientID %>").draggable({
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.draggable[0].hasAttribute("ID")) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        $("#<%= blAvailableDocuments.ClientID %>").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var source = ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id;
                var target = event.target.id;

                if (source != target) {
                    Move(ui.draggable[0], source, target);
                }
            }
        });

        $("#<%= blSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").draggable({
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.draggable[0].hasAttribute("ID")) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        $("#<%= blSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var source = ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id;
                var target = event.target.id;

                if (source != target) {
                    Move(ui.draggable[0], source, target);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function Move(element, source, target) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("li");
        var sourceBL = document.getElementById(source);
        var targetBL = document.getElementById(target);

        newLI.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        sourceBL.removeChild(element);
        targetBL.appendChild(newLI);

        PersistDocumentSelections();
    }

    function PersistDocumentSelections() {
        $("#<%= persistSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val("");
        $("#<%= blSelectedDocuments.ClientID %> li").each(function (index) {
            var value = $("#<%= persistSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val();
            value += $(this).text() + "|";
            $("#<%= persistSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val(value);
        });

        $("#<%= persistNonSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val("");
        $("#<%= blAvailableDocuments.ClientID %> li").each(function (index) {
            var value = $("#<%= persistNonSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val();
            value += $(this).text() + "|";
            $("#<%= persistNonSelectedDocuments.ClientID %>").val(value);
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to commit the changes to the `DOM` when items are being dragged/dropped/re-ordered, or to detect the order that they appear on page for the `.each()` loop ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peculiarly, The problem was that JQuery didnt recognise its own updates straight away. The solution was to delay the updating of the hidden fields by a few milliseconds.

```
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var source = ui.draggable[0].parentElement.id;
        var target = event.target.id;

        if (source != target) {
            Move(ui.draggable[0], source, target);
        }

        setTimeout(function () { PersistDocumentSelections(); }, 100);
    }
```

Also, not sure if the execution of the `drop: function` continues past the `setTimeout()` call, so meaning that the problem was the `drop: function` required to complete before the changes are committed for the `PersistDocumentSelections` method to assess them